# Add a second JavaScript function to menu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I would like to add a second JavaScript function to my menu-toggle. I want to toggle the menu list and change the class name of the toggle button within the same function.

In jQuery, I would add a line something like this `$('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-open');`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

CodePen: http://cdpn.io/roCqH

**HTML**

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation toggled" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="menu-toggle">+</h1>

    <div class="menu">
        <ul class=" nav-menu">
            <li><a>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>Sample Page</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>The Emperor’s New Clothes</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 45px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #fff;
}
.menu-open {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px SpringGreen;
}
.menu-toggle, .main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/**
 * navigation.js
 *
 * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens.
 */
( function() {
    var container, button, menu, menuToggle;

    container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
    if ( ! container )
        return;

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'h1' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button )
        return;

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    menuToggle = container.getElementsByClassName( 'menu-toggle' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) )
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';

    button.onclick = function() {

        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) )
            container.className = container.className.replace( 'toggled', '' );
        else
            container.className += 'toggled'; 
}

} )();


/* $(this).toggleClass('menu-open'); */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning to `button.onclick`, which as you've found can only have one handler assigned to it at a time, use DOM2 handlers:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Code here
}, false);
```

You can have as many of those as you like. And they live *alongside* the the `button.onclick =` kind, so you can have both that kind and a DOM2 handler.

If you need to support IE8, you have to use Microsoft's predecessor to DOM2 (yes, that's right, they got there first — and then spent a decade not updating to support the standard):

```
button.attachEvent("onclick", function() {
    // Code here
});
```

So for a simple handler that doesn't need access to the event, you can do this:

```
if (button.addEventListener) {
    button.addEventListener("click", handleTheEvent, false);
}
else if (button.attachEvent) {
    button.attachEvent("onclick", handleTheEvent);
}

function handleTheEvent() {
    // ...code here...
}
```

If it needs to do more complex things, like prevent the default action of the button, stop propagation, etc., well, that's why we have libs like jQuery, to handle those diffs for us. :-)